# C write() function not working as expected

Tags: c, function, printf, output

The program does not output the modified word . In fact it does not return anything...

If I input "Jake" for example the output on the console is:

```
Jake

Modified Name: JAKE
```

But it should further output the encrypted name. Could you help me? I think I did no mistake with the write function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char name [120];

    read(0,name,120);

    for(int i = 0; i<=119; i++){
        if(name[i] >= 'a' && name[i] <= 'z'){
            name[i] -= 32;
        }
    }

    printf("\nModified Name: %s\n",name);
    int c = 13;

    for (int i = 0; i<=119; i++){
        if(name[i] + 13 > 'Z'){
            c = i + 13 - 'Z';
            name[i] = 'A' + c;
        }else{
            name[i] = name[i] + c;
        }
    }

    write(0, name, 120);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: file descriptor is 0 in write function, why?

Comment: You should always check the return value of functions that can fail, such as `read` or `write`.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I tried with an online compiler and seems to work correctly:https://onlinegdb.com/ByA-Wd7Rb

Comment: Why you use in loop `i<=119` your input `name` may not reach to last point. This is error on last write. Express second for reason

Comment: Why are you using `read` and `write` here? Use stdio functions that can handle *lines*.

Answer (score 1):

I think writing should go to file descriptor 1 (stdout), no?

Answer (score 0):

File descriptor 0 denotes standard input ( say an input device or a file or a keyoard ) program essentially reads data from those and write to these devices most definitely fails.

> 0 - stdin

File descriptor 1 denotes standard output ( say the monitor, a file again or a disk think more ) program essentially writes data to these.

> 1 - stdout

File descriptor 2 is more or less an output device ( with some specific interpretation into handling where error goes, i.e to which device, or file, or console or .. )

> 2 - stderr

in you case

```
write( 0, ... );
```

program is essentially trying to write to an input device which possibly opened in a read mode, hence it will fail.

check below link for more information.
[wiki page here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)